# How do I connect to Windows Desktops from a Linux Server?

Tags: ssh, vpn, remote-desktop, rdp, tunnel

I have system A on a network connected to the Internet, another system B on a different place (different location also).
I have a VPS server with SSH connectivity. Both A and B are Windows, and the server is running GNU/Linux.

How would I access system B from system A using the server?
I've read many articles, but I've only found helpful results for Linux.

Comment: What has "the server" got to do with accessing `B` from `A`?

Answer (score 1):

... both `System A` and `System B` needs to utilize `Local` and `Remote` `PortForwarding`, see following article for greater details:

[SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding)

Answer (score -1):

If systems A and B are both Windows boxes with Internet access, you can use a product like GoToMyPC or LogMeIn or TeamViewer to access their desktops, regardless of what additional connectivity they may have between them. This approach also gives you a way to support both systems while away from either location.